# Editing And Uploading to remote server from Heroku app

Tags: php, heroku, ftp

hi i have a facebook app on heroku (php). i have a php page that take some data from a website adress and add some more data then upload it to ftp account. it works on any host perfectly but it doesnt work on heroku.

here is link of my php page to see what happens.
http://bangwithfriends.herokuapp.com/test.php

here is the code.

```
<?php
 $config = array
(
'ftp_user'  => 'username',
'ftp_pass'  => 'password',
'domain'    => 'domain',
'file'      => 'filepath',
);

$veri = file_get_contents("http://domain/file");
$fp = fopen($config['file'],'w');

fwrite($fp,"$veri");
fwrite($fp,"<br>");
fwrite($fp,"info to add");

fclose($fp);

$ftp = ftp_connect($config['domain']);
ftp_login($ftp,$config['ftp_user'],$config['ftp_pass']);
ftp_put($ftp,$config['file'],$config['file'],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($ftp);
```

?>

Thanks

Edit1:

the problem is in this part

```
$ftp = ftp_connect($config['domain']);
ftp_login($ftp,$config['ftp_user'],$config['ftp_pass']);
ftp_put($ftp,$config['file'],$config['file'],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($ftp);
```

?>
when i delete this part page succesfully read remote file and write extra info. how can i upload it to ftp with other code ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This isn't a complete answer

Your first problem is that Heroku doesn't come with php ftp support. You need to create and add the ftp.so extension to your app and include it in a custom php.ini file. You can find step-by-step instructions to do that here: [PHP on Heroku Again](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/)

This will get you part of the way. I'm still struggling with the `I won't open a connection to xx.xx.xx.xx (only to xx.xx.xx.xx)` errors `ftp_put()` and `ftp_get()` return, but I'll update with any news.